# Floated element do not receive mouse events

Tags: html, css

Two child elements are inside a fixed width div.

The first element is a text sentence than can be long, so the `overflow: hidden` rule is used.

The second is a floated element that must always be visible and located on the right side of the parent. This element must react to mouse events like hover and click.

The following snippet demonstrate the issue.

Mouse hover and click are tested:

- element color changes on hovering (green for the sentence, red for the float)
- clicks are visible on the console for each elements

When the sentence is short enough so that there is still some space left between the sentence and the floated element, everything works fine.

But when the sentence is long, the floated element do not receive events anymore, instead the sentence does.

Is there a way to ensure that mouse events are receive by the float element while preserving this layout?

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: black 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}

.sentence {
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.sentence:hover {
  color: green
}

.float {
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
}

.float:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">very loooooooooooooong sentence</span>
</div>

<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">short sentence</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a z-index is correct, but the z-index property only works on an element that has a non-static position. So add `position: relative` to your float rule:

```
.float {
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  position:relative;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: black 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}

.sentence {
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.sentence:hover {
  color: green
}

.float {
  float: right;
  z-index: 10;
  position:relative;
}

.float:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">very loooooooooooooong sentence</span>
</div>

<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">short sentence</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed `position: relative` seems to be enough, I can remove the `z-index`. I forgot to remove the `z-index` in my snippet it was just a test.

Answer (score 1):

I added display: block; and moved overflow:hidden; to the sentence class. This should keep the hover from working weirdly. The overflow was only "hidden" in the parent div. Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: black 1px solid;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}

.sentence {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.sentence:hover {
  color: green
}

.float {
  float: right;
}

.float:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">very loooooooooooooong sentence</span>
</div>

<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <span class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">short sentence</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sentence {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}
.sentence:hover {
  color: green
}
.float {
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
}
.float:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <div class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">very loooooooooooooong sentence</div>
</div>

<div class="parent" onclick="console.log('parent')">
  <div class="float" onclick="console.log('float')">FLOAT</div>
  <div class="sentence" onclick="console.log('sentence')">short sentence</div>
</div>
```